# "SINGLE" aggregation function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

Moderately frequently, I find myself doing a grouping, that *I* know will result in the whole group having the same value in a particular column, but SQL Server doesn't know that.

Most often, it's that I've grouped by `DATEPART(Month, my_date_column)` and then I want to `SELECT DATEPART(Year, my_date_column)` where all the data is in a single year or `SELECT DATENAME(Month, my_date_column)`

SQL Server doesn't know that these are implicitly all identical, so I end up using `MIN()` or `MAX()`.

This *works*, but it feels wrong. (And misleading for future developers!)

Is there a SINGLE() function or anything comparable?

Ideally it would error if they **weren't** all unique, but I'd taking anything that was more explicit about what I was doing.

Comment: To document your intentions, just group by it like everything else.

Comment: `SINGLE` is the misleading function. What would `SINGLE` do if it encountered a *different* value? It can't throw random errors. It could only work if somehow you ensured that all results were identical, as if you called DISTINCT on them.  That's not how aggregates are expected to work

Comment: SQL, the language, deals with data sets. Aggregate functions work on an entire set and produce a result. It's OK for a function to throw when invalid data are encountered, like NaN or NULL. It's not OK if that happens at random based on the order or distribution of the data. For such a function to work deterministically the rest of the query would have to ensure that all values are identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use `MIN`. There are only 13 [aggregate functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) and there's nothing that is *more* suitable.

If you wish to document that the result should be unique for the group and that multiple values are an error, put a tripwire in:

```
...
MIN(Expression) as a,
CASE WHEN MIN(Expression) != MAX(Expression) THEN 1/0 END as EnsureUnique,
...
```

The alternative is to write your own [CLR Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131057.aspx) function for this.

Comment: A SQLCLR aggregate that randomly throws *after* the results are selected isn't the best idea. Which is why SQL, the language, doesn't have such an aggregate function. You can't have an aggregate function that may throw even though the data is perfectly valid (ie not NULL or extremes). It would also cause serious performance problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - *personally*, I'd just use the `MIN` and not be looking to generate errors. Having said that, I'd still prefer any variation of this aggregate over the [tag:mysql] "it's not in an aggregate, it's not in a `GROUP BY`, I'll just give you a random value from one of the rows".

Comment: You could also use `FIRST_VALUE`, if it doesn't introduce additional sorting. MySQL doesn't have windowing functions so it uses various tricks like `previous + 1` to calculate row numbers